# escape dictionary key double quotes when doing println dictionary item in Swift

Tags: println, swift

I've been playing around with Swift, and just came across an issue. 
I have the following Dictionary in:

```
var locations:Dictionary<String,CLLocationCoordinate2D> = ["current":CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lng) ];

println("current locaition is \(locations["current"])")
```

but the compiler is complaining about double quotes around `current` which represent the a key in my dictionary.

I tried escaping it with `\` but it wasn't the right way.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Isn't the type returned from `locations["current"]` a `CLLocationCoordinate2D?` as in an optional type: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Dictionary.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014608-CH4-SW7

Answer (score 42, accepted):

**Xcode 7.1+**

Since Xcode 7.1 beta 2, we can now use quotations within string literals.  From the release notes:

> Expressions interpolated in strings may now contain string literals. For example, "My name is (attributes["name"]!)" is now a valid expression. (14050788)

**Xcode <7.1**

I don't think you can do it that way.

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-XID_368)

> The expressions you write inside parentheses within an interpolated string cannot contain an unescaped double quote (") or backslash (\), and cannot contain a carriage return or line feed.

You'd have to use

```
let someVar = dict["key"]
println("Some words \(someVar)")
```

Comment: This is such a bummer of an answer but thanks @Logan for making it gentle!

Comment: Why would somebody downvote this?  It's not my fault you can't do what you want, and I literally quoted the documentation?

Answer (score 10):

You can use string concatenation instead of interpolation:

```
println("Some words " + dict["key"]! + " some more words.")
```

Just mind the spaces around the `+` signs.

*UPDATE:*

Another thing you can do is to use [string format specifiers](https://thatthinginswift.com/string-formatting/) the same way how it was done back in the objective-c days:

```
println( String(format: "Some words %@ some more words", dict["1"]!) )
```

Answer (score 3):

I've had this problem too with interpolating strings. The best solution I found was just to split it into two lines like so:

```
let location = locations["current"]
println("current locaition is \(location)")
```

It may be a bug with Swift. From what I found in the docs, you should be able to use \ to escape quotes.

Comment: You can use escape quotes, but not inside of parenthesis.  See my answer.

Comment: That's what confuses me. It sounds like you can include escaped double quotes, but you escape them with backslash which isn't allowed.

Comment: I didn't even realize that.  It's basically saying, you can't do it unless you fix it ... but also, you're not allowed to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

Swift doesn't accept quote in \(). Therefore you need to separate the one-line code into two.

Here is a blog showing example for Chinese readers:
http://tw.gigacircle.com/321945-1

Answer (score 0):

Since Swift 2.1 you can use double quotes on interpolation. `println("current location is \(locations["current"])")`