# Can you use string/character literals within Swift string interpolation?

Tags: swift

Is it possible to use a String/Character literal within string interpolation in Swift?

The language reference says:

> The expression you write inside parentheses within an interpolated string cannot contain an unescaped double quote (") ...

That's a little fuzzy to me, since it seems to deliberately leave the loophole of escaped double quotes.

If I try:

```
println( "Output: \(repeat("H",20))" );

func repeat( char:Character, times:Int ) -> String {
    var output:String = "";
    for index in 1...times {
        output += char;
    }
    return output;
}
```

I get "Expected ',' separator".

Similarly, if I do the same thing, but escape the quotes, still no dice:

```
println( "Output: \(repeat(\"H\",20))" );
```

I suspect it's just not possible, and to be honest, no big deal -- I haven't found any example that I can't easily solve by doing a little work before the string interpolation, I guess I'm just looking for confirmation that it's just not possible.

Comment: `println("Output: " + repeat("H", 20) + "");`, maybe? the last `""` would not have been necessary to be added.

Comment: Confirmed that @holex's solution works well.

Comment: Sure, that totally works -- but it's not string interpolation, it's just string concatenation.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a solution to your problem but when you use for in loop -> when your not using `index` simply do `for _ in 1...times`

Comment: possible duplicate of [escape dictionary key double quotes when doing println dictionary item in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24024754/escape-dictionary-key-double-quotes-when-doing-println-dictionary-item-in-swift)

Comment: let value = repeat("H",20)
println( "Output: \(value)"); @Narendra G

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done starting in Swift 2.1:
http://www.russbishop.net/swift-2-1

Prior to that, it wasn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it's:

```
let strfunc = repeat("H",20) as string
println( "Output: \(strfunc)" );
```

Comment: Yeah, again, a perfectly fine solution to the problem I don't have. ;) There are lots of ways to get a repeated character into a string with or without interpolation. What I was really trying to verify is that there is no way to use a string literal within a Swift string interpolation expression. There doesn't seem to be.